# How to add a remote namespace to OntClass with Jena

Tags: namespaces, jena, ontology, semantic-web, foaf

I'm new to Jena and the Semantic web.

I'm now making a model having an OntClass "Person" using Jena. This is what I've tried:

```
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
String NS = http://purl.org/ontology#
model.setNsPrefix("Ont", NS);

model.setNsPrefix("foaf", "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1#");  
OntClass person = model.createClass(NS + "Person");

person.setSameAs(FOAF.Person);
person.addProperty(FOAF.account, "account");
```

But it doesn't seem working because when generating the Turtle file, I receive:

```
Ont:Person  a    owl:Class ;
        owl:sameAs    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person> ;
        <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/account>
                "account" .
```

instead of having:

```
@prefix foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#> .

Ont:Person  a    owl:Class ;
            owl:sameAs    foaf:Person ;
            foaf:account        "account" .
```

So what is the right way to link a OntClass in OntModel to a remote namespace ?in this case it's to link my OntClass person to "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1#"

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just have to replace:

```
model.setNsPrefix("foaf", "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1#");
```

with

```
model.setNsPrefix("foaf", FOAF.getURI());
```

and it works!